# AttributeError: object has no attribute 'published' when parsing CNN source

Tags: python-3.x, feedparser

I'm facing this problem since parsing CNN.RSS site. It only get first 7 entries then i get this problem. Below it my log .. Please help me :(. Thanks you

This is my code:

```
import feedparser

url = "http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss"
feed = feedparser.parse(url)
for news in feed.entries:
    print(news.published)
```

[Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iCnG.png)

My log:
https://pastebin.com/vMJSXD0J

Comment: there is key error for `published` check if `published` is defined or not in your code or if you have imported all the dependencies. Also you are doing the iteration and attaching the attribute to the iteration variable itself which does not seem to be correct way. You need to provide the the detailed code

Comment: I swear this is my latest and fully code.I''m just starting to learn to use this library and this bug is give me crazy

Answer (score 0):

To debug this you should first check if `published` is a part of the `keys` for `news` or not.

```
>>> news.keys()
dict_keys(['title', 'title_detail', 'summary', 'summary_detail', 'links', 'link', 'id', 'guidislink', 'published', 'published_parsed', 'media_content'])
```

According to this `published` is a part of the `keys` for `news` so your code should work which actually does work.

```
>>> import feedparser
>>> url = "http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss"
>>> feed = feedparser.parse(url)
>>> for news in feed.entries:
    print(news.published)

    
Thu, 11 Mar 2021 04:53:36 GMT
Thu, 11 Mar 2021 03:21:32 GMT
Wed, 10 Mar 2021 12:54:12 GMT
Thu, 11 Mar 2021 05:13:03 GMT
Wed, 10 Mar 2021 23:46:07 GMT
Wed, 10 Mar 2021 17:56:03 GMT
Thu, 11 Mar 2021 05:50:56 GMT
Thu, 11 Mar 2021 00:37:19 GMT
Thu, 11 Mar 2021 04:44:57 GMT
Wed, 10 Mar 2021 03:46:09 GMT
Wed, 10 Mar 2021 13:24:02 GMT
Thu, 11 Mar 2021 05:37:44 GMT
Thu, 11 Mar 2021 01:48:41 GMT
Wed, 10 Mar 2021 17:13:52 GMT
Thu, 11 Mar 2021 03:43:19 GMT
Thu, 11 Mar 2021 05:11:13 GMT
'
'
etc
```

PS - This is implemented on Python 3.9